# Where should I place .htaccess to take effect in a particular site?

Tags: .htaccess

We have an Apache web server that contains several Drupal 7 installations. Where should I place a .htaccess file in order for its contents to take effect on a particular website?

I tried putting it here `/opt/apache/var/www/html/drupal-7.19/sites/thewebsitename` but it didn't work.

Comment: What kind of things are you trying to do?  There may be an alternate solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a multi-site Drupal installation (ie. folders other than 'all' and 'default' in your `/opt/apache/var/www/html/drupal-7.19/sites/` directory), then you cannot have a separate .htaccess file for each site, and must place your changes in the common .htaccess which should already exist in `/opt/apache/var/www/html/drupal-7.19/`. Note that as these changes will apply to all of your multi-sites, you need to ensure your rules don't break sites you're not interested in.

If you have a more traditional installation of one site per one Drupal instance, then you'll still be modifying the same .htaccess file in `/opt/apache/var/www/html/drupal-7.19/`, but don't have to worry about breaking other sites.

Comment: I guess  [this]http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44023/specific-htaccess-in-some-sites-on-multisite is what you are looking for.